# click anchor inside a highslide event

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

I'm using the [HighSlide](http://highslide.com/) library to show an external HTML page in a iFrame. Once the external HTML content has been loaded I want to navigate to an anchor/hash link inside the iframe. I'm using the onAfterExpand event to try to click my link, but the click is not performed:

```
$('.show-hidden-comment').click(function()
{
    var anchorId = $(this).attr('id');

    hs.Expander.prototype.onAfterExpand = function (sender)
    {
        var body = sender.body;
        var iFrame = $(body).find("iframe");
        var anchorLink = iFrame.contents().find("#" + anchorId);
        anchorLink.click();
    }; 

    return hs.htmlExpand(this, { objectType: 'iframe' });
});
```

Comment: The `.click()`, assuming the ID is correct, will finction fine...the common misconception here is that a `.click()` on an anchor goes to the `href`...it does not.

Comment: @Nick: Yes, it works perfect in the parent page, but in the iframe (and maybe because is inside the library's onAfterExpand event) does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asked in their Highslide forum:

http://highslide.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=8734